# C program to print trapezoid pattern of numbers,stars & hypens

Tags: c

I was asked this in a test today.

I had to print the following pattern:-

For example if the user input n=4 then the output should be of this pattern-
1*2*3*4*17*18*19*20
--5*6*7*14*15*16
----8*9*12*13
------10*11

Again if N=5 the code should print
1*2*3*4*5*26*27*28*29*30
--6*7*8*9*22*23*24*25
----10*11*12*19*20*21
------13*14*17*18
--------15*16

I could manage to print the pattern partially...help..
Progress so far...

```
#include <stdio.h>
void pattern(int);
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    pattern(n);
    return 0;
}
void pattern(int n)
{
    int i,j,k=1,l=2,h;
    for(i=n;i>0;i--)
    {
        if(i<n)
            {
                for(h=1;h<=l;h++)
                    printf("-");
                    l=l+2;
            }
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
            printf("%d",k);
            k++;
            if(j!=i)
                printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");  
    }
}
```

This prints for n=4:-

```
4  
1*2*3*4  
--5*6*7  
----8*9  
------10
```

Comment: Have you got yourself a new ID? Anyway - Why do you think that the first line does not work properly? Why not use a debugger?

Comment: PS: First line requires 8 numbers - so `for(i=n;i>0;i--)` should at least be `for(i=2*n;i>0;i--)`

Comment: i didnot get a new id....i am new to stackoverflow...

Comment: i found a pattern...for input n we have print n*(n+1) numbers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go :

```
#include<stdio.h>
void pattern(int);
int main()
{
  int n;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  pattern(n);
  return 0;
}
void pattern(int n)
{
  int i,j,k=1,l=2,h;
  int rest=n*(n+1)+1,rn=0;

  for(i=n;i>0;i--)
    {
      if(i<n)
        {
          for(h=1;h<=l;h++)
            printf("-");
          l=l+2;
        }
      for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
          printf("%d",k);
          k++;           
          printf("*");
        }

      rest=rest-i;
      rn=rest;

      for(int p=1;p<=i;p++)
        {      
          printf("%d",rn);
          rn++;
          if(p!=i)
            printf("*");

        }
      printf("\n");  
    }
}
```

I see you did a good job in printing the hypens and half the numbers. So all that was left was the other half which should be decremented with each line.
The highest number we need to print is n*(n+1).
So we compute that number (in the variable rest) and then we need to decrement that each line with i(half of the number of elements on a row).

Comment: It is also a good idea to always use braces in loops/if statements

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int pattern(int);

int pattern(int t)
{
    int i, n, j, max = 1, k, max1, no=1, l, no2, s = 1;
    printf("enter the no of rows");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    max1 = n;
    no2=(n*n)+1;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
    /* PRINTING "-" FROM 2ND LINE SO J=2 AND PRINTING LIKHE 2 4 6 SO MAX= MAX+2 */
        for(j=2;j<=max;j++)
        {
            printf("-");
        }
        max = max + 2;
        /* PRINTING FIRST SET OF NOS 1 2 3 2ND LINE 4 5 DEN 6 SO NO++  */
        for(k=1;k<=max1;k++)
        {
            printf("%d*",no);
            no++;
        }
        /* PRINTING 2ND NOS NO2 = N*N+1 COZ N=5 */
        for(l=1;l<=max1-1;l++)
        {
            printf("%d*",no2);
            no2++;
        }
        /* printing last no without star*/
        printf("%d",no2);
        max1--;
        /* then initializing the 2nd line starting no */    
        no2 = no2 - 2 * (n - s);
        s++;
        printf("\n");   
    }
}


int main()
{
    int p = pattern(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main( )
{
 int n,n1,n2,n3,i,j,*arr;
 printf("enter the number\n");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 n1=1;
 n2=n*(n+1);
 n3=(2*n)-1;
 arr=(int*)calloc(n*2,sizeof(int));
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
   for(j=i;j<n;j++)
     arr[j]=n1++;
   for(j=n3-i;j>=5;j--)
     arr[j]=n2--;
   for(j=0;j<i;j++)
     printf("--");
   printf("%d",arr[i]);
   for(j=i+1;j<2*n-i;j++)
     printf("*%d",arr[j]);
   printf("\n");
  }
 free(arr);
}
```